# Unable to Delete space in confluence

Tags: confluence

My user is unable to delete space.

when i check the log its throwing below exceptions.

please suggest me.

> org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: Hibernate
>   operation: could not delete:
>   [com.atlassian.confluence.pages.Attachment#10289727]; SQL []; The
>   DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint
>   "FK9DC3E34D34A4917E". The conflict occurred in database "wiki", table
>   "dbo.ATTACHMENTDATA", column 'ATTACHMENTID'.; nested exception is
>   java.sql.SQLException: The DELETE statement conflicted with the
>   REFERENCE constraint "FK9DC3E34D34A4917E". The conflict occurred in
>   database "wiki", table "dbo.ATTACHMENTDATA", column 'ATTACHMENTID'.
>   Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: The DELETE statement conflicted with
>   the REFERENCE constraint "FK9DC3E34D34A4917E". The conflict occurred
>   in database "wiki", table "dbo.ATTACHMENTDATA", column 'ATTACHMENTID'.

regards,
tousif shaikh

Comment: This is really just a guess, but maybe it's preventing you from deleting the space because other spaces are referencing attachments ON that space. Also, you should check the permissions your user has to make sure they CAN delete that space.

Answer (score 2):

Generally, only a wiki administrator should remove a space.

Try:

1. delete all of the pages in the space
2. purge the space trash
3. delete the space permissions `/spaces/spacepermissions.action?key=<spacekey>` except confluence administrators
4. then delete the space

If that fails, a wiki administrator could try using the [Confluence CLI](https://bobswift.atlassian.net/wiki/display/CSOAP/) "[removeSpace](https://bobswift.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/CSOAP/pages/1066778134/removeSpace)" command to delete the space.